# Reading images to create dataset for image classification

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a classifier based in keras and tensorflow on my images data.

The images are located as sub folders inside folders:

```
data
    train
        terror
        no_terror
    test
        terror
        no_terror
```

The problem here is that, I have all the images which are of different sizes.

I am using the code below.

```
TERROR_TRAIN_DIR = 'C://Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/Dhivy/data/train/terror/'
TERROR_TEST_DIR = 'C://Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/Dhivy/data/test/terror/'

NON_TERROR_TRAIN_DIR = 'C://Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/Dhivy/data/train/non-terror/'
NON_TERROR_TEST_DIR = 'C://Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/Dhivy/data/test/non-terror/'

ROWS = 64
COLS = 64
CHANNELS = 3

terror_train_images = [TERROR_TRAIN_DIR+i for i in os.listdir(TERROR_TRAIN_DIR)] 
terror_test_images = [TERROR_TEST_DIR+i for i in os.listdir(TERROR_TEST_DIR)] 

non_terror_train_images = [NON_TERROR_TRAIN_DIR+i for i in os.listdir(NON_TERROR_TRAIN_DIR)] 
non_terror_test_images = [NON_TERROR_TEST_DIR+i for i in os.listdir(NON_TERROR_TEST_DIR)] 



def read_image(file_path):
    img = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) #cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE
    return cv2.resize(img, (ROWS, COLS), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)


def prep_data(images):
    count = len(images)
    data = np.ndarray((count, CHANNELS, ROWS, COLS), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i, image_file in enumerate(images):
        image = read_image(image_file)
        data[i] = image.T
        if i%250 == 0: print('Processed {} of {}'.format(i, count))

    return data

terror_train_images = prep_data(terror_train_images)
terror_test_images = prep_data(terror_test_images)

non_terror_train_images = prep_data(non_terror_train_images)
non_terror_test_images = prep_data(non_terror_test_images)
```

I am getting the error shown below.

```
<ipython-input-27-4eadf011e89d> in read_image(file_path)
      1 def read_image(file_path):
      2     img = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) #cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE
----> 3     return cv2.resize(img, (ROWS, COLS), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
      4 
      5 

error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Is there any way, I can create train and test dataset with labels as well, from the folder structure itself and create X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test, which I can feed directly into VGG and Resnet, my main gaol is to test how these images perform on these pre-trained models.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you checkout https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html ?

Comment: No, will it work images of different size

Comment: Yes, they use resizing. Try to follow this (or one of many others) tutorial.

Comment: I am trying, if you can, please help me in the same

Comment: You're passing an empty image to the function (hence the error `!ssize.empty()`). Your images list built by `os.listdir` contains some paths that aren't images (or are otherwise not able to be read as an image). Print out your file list and find the culprits. Probably in your list comprehension you can only add them `if i.endswith('.jpg')` or whatever filetypes you're using.

Comment: its working actually, let me try, give me a minute, if it worked, please provide this as answer.